# slow conditional formatting rule (look for an alternative)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas, conditional-formatting

I am looking for an alternative to my current conditional formatting rule. The rule is as follows:

`=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({" + grpOneStr + "},  A1))))`

I build the variable according to how the formula should be used which is explained here: [https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/multiple-search-in-single-search-formula-google-sheets/#:~:text=We%20can%20use%20multiple%20search,more%20than%20one%20search%20string](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/multiple-search-in-single-search-formula-google-sheets/#:%7E:text=We%20can%20use%20multiple%20search,more%20than%20one%20search%20string).

A snippet of the script I use is as follows:

```
// conditional formatting
  var grpOneStr = "Confirmed, Confirmed (Paid)";
  var grpTwoStr = "Sent, Posted (Threshold)";
  var grpThreeStr = "Cancelled, Complete";

  var grpOneFormula = "=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({\"Confirmed\",\"Confirmed (Paid)\"},  A1))))";
  var grpTwoFormula = "=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({\"Sent\",\"Posted (Threshold)\"},  A1))))";
  var grpThreeFormula = "=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({\"Cancelled\",\"Complete\"},  A1))))";

  var grpOneRule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenFormulaSatisfied(grpOneFormula)
  .setBackground('#4fbbbf')
  .setRanges([promoSheet.getRange(1, 1, promoMaxRow, promoMaxCol)])
  .build();
```

The reason I am looking for an alternative is because the current formula slows down my script considerably at times. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Although unfortunately, I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheet, I proposed a workaround for achieving your goal. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to look for a workaround for achieving your current situation using your script by reducing the process cost.

As a workaround, how about using OnEdit trigger and TextFinder? In this workaround, the following flow is run.

1. Edit a cell in a sheet.
2. Check all cells of the data range using TextFinder. And, the background color is set.

When this flow is reflected in a Google Apps Script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set your sheet name. In this script, "Sheet1" is used. And, please set `obj`.

When you use this script, please edit the cell. For example, when "Confirmed" is put to the cell, the background of the cell is changed.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1") return;

  // Please set patterns and colors.
  const obj = [
    { pattern: ["Confirmed", "Confirmed \\(Paid\\)"], color: '#4fbbbf' },
    { pattern: ["Sent", "Posted \\(Threshold\\)"], color: '#4fbbbf' },
    { pattern: ["Cancelled", "Complete"], color: '#4fbbbf' },
  ];

  const r = sheet.getDataRange().setBackground(null);
  obj.forEach(({ pattern, color }) => {
    const rangeList = r.createTextFinder(pattern.join("|")).useRegularExpression(true).findAll().map(r => r.getA1Notation());
    sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setBackground(color);
  });
}
```

- In this script, all cells of the data range are updated. If you want to update only the edited cell, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const r = sheet.getDataRange().setBackground(null);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const r = range.setBackground(null);
    ```

#### Note:

- If your sheet has still conditional format rules, please remove them and test this script.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createTextFinder(String))

Comment: thank you, i will test this approach and see if it can bring down the processing time vs. my current solution

Comment: @dan Thank you for replying. In the above script, all cells are checked. But, if you want to update only the edited cell, please test the bottom method.